# Android Geofence Lifecycle

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm working on SDK that is using GeoFences from Google Play Services. Everything seems to work just fine. I'm adding my geofences like this (it's done in method called from activity):

```
locationClient.addGeofences(geofences, GeoFencesUtils.getTransitionPendingIntent(context), this);
```

The pending intent is send to BroadcastReceiver in which notification is created.

I'm wondering how excaly this geofences is stored in system, and when could it be lost (or deleted by OS). For example when Activity in which created geofences is destroyed, I'm still able to receive broadcast. When should I recreate those geofence? On system boot? Or maybe once created it will be stored in google play services for ever and I don't have to worry about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geofences are removed whenever the network location provider is disabled by the user or when the system reboots.

See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html#addGeofences%28java.util.List%3Ccom.google.android.gms.location.Geofence%3E,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient.OnAddGeofencesResultListener%29)

See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20367307/2733881)

Comment: I have one more question http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html i really don't understanding why is *Presistent Storage* i.e `SharedPrefrences` used here?