# Do geofences survive app updates?

Tags: android, google-play-services, geofencing

I know Google Play Services Geofences [don't survive a device reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040889/are-android-geofences-surviving-a-reboot?rq=1) and I've become paranoid and asked my self what happens on an app update.
I have tested in development changing the `versionCode` of the manifest and running the app again to simulate an update and the app continues to work.

Is this the correct way to test this?
Is there any information about what happens to previously registered geofences after an app update?

Comment: I re-register geofences at almost every opportunity in my Android app but still it seems like after a re-register and app update, sometimes the geofence transitions are not being delivered to the new app correctly. It's almost like the geofences are trying to deliver to the old app instance still. I haven't found a good solution to this other than rebooting the device yet, keen to hear other experiences.